# How to show a DirectX/VMR window on multiple monitors (all of them)

Tags: c++, winapi, video, directx, multiple-monitors

I have got a legacy MFC program that **plays a video using VMR9/DirectX 9**. There is a request to add support for multiple monitors. The program window should **extend to all available monitors**.

I am working on laptop (Dell Precision) with second monitor attached, also Dell. Both monitors, laptop and external, have the same resolution.
When I am running my application, I am using the following code to define a total screen size:

```
CRect GetVirtualDesktopDimension()
{
    CRect rectWhole;
    ::SetRect( rectWhole, 
                ::GetSystemMetrics( SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN ),
                ::GetSystemMetrics( SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN ),
                ::GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN ),
                ::GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN ) );
    return rectWhole;
}
```

Then I do

```
    CRect myRect = GetVirtualDesktopDimension();
    myWindow->SetWindowPos(0, 0, 0, myRect.Width(), myRect.Height(), SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

**The result is absolutely weird**: The window indeed takes the whole of both monitors, I have checked it with Spy.

- The left part, the part shown on the internal laptop
  monitor, is shown correctly.
- The right part, the part of the external monitor, is hidden.
  I just see the external monitor's desktop.

However, if I do something like

```
myWindow->SetWindowPos(0, 100, 100, myRect.Width(), myRect.Height(), SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

then things go the other way,

- the left part, shown on the internal laptop monitor, is black,
- the right part, the part of the external monitor, is shown
  correctly.

**EDIT 1**
Have checked it on a desktop computer with 3 attached monitors. The same problem remains, meaning it is not a specific graphic card/adapter issue.

How can I solve this?

Comment: DirectX is the troublemaker of course.  There are some notes about it in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Unlikely to be helpful when you don't use exclusive mode.

Comment: I presume your desktop is rectangular

Comment: Yes, both set at 1920x1080 resolution